How to modify frequency of an analog signal
I want to create my own pcb. First step is to design my circuit. I thought about a voice modifier.
So, in the breadboard I should put:

a microphone (an electrostatic electret microphone)
followed by an amplifier (maybe op amp)
I will most likely use a bandpass filter from 20hz to 20kHz (audible
bandwidth).

Then ... I really don't know how to make the voice deeper. Physically I know that I have to reduce the frenquence of my input signal. But how to proceed.
Should I use a frequency divider such as CD4040 for instance ?
Do not hesitate to criticize in order to improve my circuit.

There is no circuit to improve, voice band does not go to 20 MHz, and CD4040 is a digital chip unable to process audio.

My mistake @Justme indeed. Is there a chip that process audio ?

Minor note: In English you'd call it an analog (or analogue, if you're british) signal; analogic isn't a word.

Firstly, the audio spectrum is up to 20kHz, not 20MHz.
Secondly, voice manipulation is hard, especially for a newcomer to electronics. Typically older systems digitally sampled 20ms of audio and played it back over 40ms, effectively halving the frequency over the entire spectrum.
Newer designs will take a fourier transform of the audio, to obtain the signal in the frequency domain. Then all harmonics are shifted down the spectrum by some amount, and an inverse fourier transform returns the signal to the time domain for playback.
I am unaware of any other ways to achieve this.
I think this is more than anyone can start their electronics journey with, unless you are some kind of genius that can pick all this up in a week. If you're still interested, look up digital signal processors (DSP), analogue to digital converters (ADC) and digital to analog converters (DAC).

The range of human hearing is generally taken as 20 Hz to 20 kHz, voice is more like 300 Hz to 3 kHz.
To lower the frequency of a signal there are a number of approaches, a few of them are:
Using a divider as you suggested, but that doesn't tend to work well for analog signals as they have to be converted to square waves first causing a lot of distortion. This is actually done in some guitar effects called octave dividers.
Digital signal processing where the signal is digitized with an ADC, some math applied to the digital data, and it's then converted back to analog with a DAC.
Heterodyning. The signal is mixed with a higher frequency carrier, the mixer output is then mixed with another carrier with a slightly different frequency which shifts the signal by the difference in the two carriers.
For example you could mix 300 to 3000 Hz with a 20 kHz carrier, this would give you the sum and difference frequencies of 17000 - 19700 Hz and 20300 - 23000 Hz. Filter out the lower range and mix the 20300 - 23000 with a 20100 Hz carrier, this will give you difference products of 200 - 2900 Hz so you've lowered the frequencies by 100 Hz. The mixers and filters needed to do this are going to be on the complicated side.
This is all a bit beyond beginner level stuff, you might want to start with something simpler.
